# Touchscreen: Select small zones from a huge scrollable image

Tags: android, scrolling, touch-screen, selection, smartphone

My app lets the user take a picture of a sheet of paper, then select a block of 2-3 words, then another block.

The user must be able to clearly read the (potentially tiny) written words, so she will zoom. The image must be scrollable to find the block, then go to the second block.

With dragging already dedicated to image scrolling, How to implement rectangle selection?

Maybe tap on first corner, then tap on opposite corner? But it does not sound very user friendly, because the rectangle is not seen during selection.

Maybe tap to "switch to selection mode", then drag rectangle? This would work well for a small selection, but it becomes unusable if the selection is larger than the screen.

What would be a user-friendly way to implement this?

*Context if needed: I am writing a flashcard app for Android, the user can take a picture of her paper notebook after a foreign language lesson, and quickly select word+definition to generate flashcards. Must support Android all the way back to 1.6, including devices without multi-touch.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Android, **long-press** is a [common gesture](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/gestures.html) for triggering selection:

> Enters data selection mode. Allows you to select one or more items in a view and act upon the data using a contextual action bar. Avoid using long press for showing contextual menus.

Thus, I'd agree with @Sherpanaut's answer (edit 2) and consider using long-press to begin drawing the selection rectangle, and then drag and lift your finger to complete the rectangle. A side benefit of using long-press versus simple touch and drag is that you'll likely minimize accidental rectangle drawing, since those gestures are fairly universally used for exploration and navigation in the context of images.

You may also want to use a [help overlay](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/help.html) to teach the user how to do this the first time around, since this gestures may not be discoverable for all users.

Comment: Great idea! In this scenario, when selecting a rectangle larger than the screen, would the app scroll the image when the user's finger reaches the screen's edge? Or should I refrain from implementing scroll-while-selecting?

Comment: That is a tricky scenario as it is often quite **difficult for the user to control the drag while the viewport is also panning**. You could limit them to only dragging within a fixed area and requiring a zoom out to make a larger selection. If you have the time/resources try out both and see which works best for your users.

Comment: @Roman Most definitely, a help overlay delivered at the right time is essential. Users are still learning when it comes to touchscreen interactions :)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I would say the app should scroll when the user's finger reaches the edge.

Comment: @Sherpanaut one alternative is you could support scroll-during-selection using multi-finger touch gestures. That is, one finger is selecting, and the other could be scrolling/zooming.

Comment: @RomanNurik: We must support devices that don't have multi-touch.

Comment: @RomanNurik To be honest that sounds horribly complicated and confusing. Do you know of any existing apps that work in this way?

Comment: @Sherpanaut IMO, multi-finger gestures shouldn't be the primary interaction, I'd start with just long press.

Comment: Single finger touch is a requirement stated by @NicolasRaoul. The mode switch will allow for this. The addition of a zoom control would also allow for selections without moving the viewport at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

Is the touchscreen multitouch or single touch?

**Multi-touch** - I would use a two finger drag to pan up/down/left/right with a pinch to zoom. Then use a single finger to draw your selections

**Single-touch** - In this case, you will need a button to switch between navigation mode and selection mode.

**Edit** - I just saw your context so assuming multi-touch as Android.

**Edit 2** - I thought about this a little more and wondered what the convention actually is. Take Google Maps, that uses single finger scrolling with a long press to drop a marker. I don't think you can draw shapes on the mobile app though.

Comment: We must support single-touch devices too. Sorry I should have mentioned it earlier.

Comment: About the single-touch case: Just to make sure I understand, what would be written on the button? Something like "Switch to selection mode"/"Switch to zoom mode"?

Comment: I mean you can do this lots of ways. You could have the button switch so when in selection mode it says "zoom mode" and vice versa.  
You could also have a toggle switch so the user can see that there are two distinct modes and see which one is active - this would mean you don't need the words "switch to...".

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Check out this [toggle switch](http://dribbble.com/shots/122755-Toggle-switch?list=searches&tag=toggle) - if you replaced **Lorem** with **Zoom** and **Ipsum** with **Select** then you would have a very clear mode switcher. What you think?